# Java TargetDataLine not picking up any audio?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, audio, signal-processing, wav

I'm writing a function to capture an audio clip for ~ 7.5 seconds using a TargetDataLine. The code executes and renders an 'input.wav' file, but when I play it there is no sound.

My approach, as shown in the code at the bottom of this post, is to do the following things:

1. Create an AudioFormat and get the Info for a Target Data Line.
2. Create the Target Data Line by getting the line from AudioSystem.
3. Open and Start the TargetDataLine, which allocates system resources for recording.
4. Create an auxiliary Thread that will record audio by writing to a file.
5. Start the auxiliary Thread, pause the main Thread in the meantime, and then close out the Target Data Line in order to stop recording.

What I have tried so far:

1. Changing the AudioFormat. Initially, I was using the other AudioFormat constructor which takes the file type as well (where the first argument is AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED etc). I had a sample rate of 44100, 16 bits, 2 channels and small-Endian settings on the other format, which yielded the same result.
2. Changing the order of commands on my auxiliary and main Thread (i.e. performing TLine.open() or start() in alternate locations).
3. Checking that my auxiliary thread does actually start.

For reference I am using IntelliJ on a Mac OS Big Sur.

```
public static void captureAudio() {
        try {
            AudioFormat f = new AudioFormat(22050, 8, 1, false, false);
            DataLine.Info secure = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, f);
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(secure)) {
                System.err.println("Unsupported Line");
            }
            TargetDataLine tLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(secure);
            System.out.println("Starting recording...");
            tLine.open(f);
            tLine.start();
            File writeTo = new File("input.wav");
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            AudioInputStream is = new AudioInputStream(tLine);
                            AudioSystem.write(is, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, writeTo);
                        } catch(IOException e) {
                            System.err.println("Encountered system I/O error in recording:");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            };
            t.start();
            Thread.sleep(7500);
            tLine.stop();
            tLine.close();
            System.out.println("Recording has ended.");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

***Update 1: Some new testing and results***

1. My microphone and speakers are both working with other applications - recorded working audio with QuickTimePlayer.
2. I did a lot of testing around what my TargetDataLines are and what the deal is with them. I ran the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
AudioFormat f = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);
        //DataLine.Info inf = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, f);
        try {
            TargetDataLine line = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(f);
            DataLine.Info test = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, f);
            TargetDataLine other = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(test);
            String output = line.equals(other) ? "Yes" : "No";
            if (output.equals("No")) {
                System.out.println(other.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(line.toString());
            System.out.println("_______________________________");
            for (Mixer.Info i : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
                Line.Info[] tli = AudioSystem.getMixer(i).getTargetLineInfo();
                if (tli.length != 0) {
                   Line comp = AudioSystem.getLine(tli[0]);
                   System.out.println(comp.toString() + ":" +i.getName());
                   if (comp.equals(line) || comp.equals(other)) {
                       System.out.println("The TargetDataLine is from " + i.getName());
                   }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Long story short, the TargetDataLine I receive from doing
`TargetDataLine line = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(f);` and
`TargetDataLine other = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, f));`
are different, **and furthermore, don't match any of the TargetDataLines that are associated with my system's mixers.**

The output of the above code was this (where there first lines are `other` and `line` respectively):

```
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@cc34f4d
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@17a7cec2
_______________________________
com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$PortMixerPort@79fc0f2f:Port MacBook Pro Speakers
com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$PortMixerPort@4d405ef7:Port ZoomAudioDevice
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@3f91beef:Default Audio Device
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@1a6c5a9e:MacBook Pro Microphone
com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@37bba400:ZoomAudioDevice
```

3. Upon this realization I manually loaded up all the TargetDataLines from my mixers and tried recording audio with each of them to see if I got any sound.

I used the following method to collect all the TargetDataLines:

```
public static ArrayList<Line.Info> allTDL() {
        ArrayList<Line.Info> all = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Mixer.Info i : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
            Line.Info[] tli = AudioSystem.getMixer(i).getTargetLineInfo();
            if (tli.length != 0) {
                for (int f = 0; f < tli.length; f += 1) {
                    all.add(tli[f]);
                }
            }
        }
        return all;
    }
```

My capture/record audio method remained the same, except for switching the format to `AudioFormat f = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);`, changing the recording time to 5000 milliseconds, and writing the method header as `public static void recordAudio(Line.Info inf)` so I could load each TargetDataLine individually with it's info.

I then executed the following code to rotate TargetDataLines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (Line.Info inf : allTDL()) {
            recordAudio(inf);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!soundless(loadAsBytes("input.wav"))) {
                System.out.println("The recording with " + inf.toString() + " has sound!");
            }
            System.out.println("The last recording with " + inf.toString() + " was soundless.");
        }

    }
}
```

The output was as such:

```
Recording...
Was unable to cast com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$PortMixerPort@506e1b77 to a TargetDataLine.
End recording.
The last recording with SPEAKER target port was soundless.
Recording...
Was unable to cast com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$PortMixerPort@5e9f23b4 to a TargetDataLine.
End recording.
The last recording with ZoomAudioDevice target port was soundless.
Recording...
End recording.
The last recording with interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes was soundless.
Recording...
End recording.
The last recording with interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes was soundless.
Recording...
End recording.
The last recording with interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes was soundless.
```

**TL;DR** the audio came out soundless for every TargetDataLine.
For completeness, here are the `soundless` and `loadAsBytes` functions:

```
 public static byte[] loadAsBytes(String name) {
        assert name.contains(".wav");
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File retrieve = new File("src/"+ name);
        try {
            InputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(retrieve);

            int read;
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = input.read(b)) > 0) {
                out.write(b, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            byte[] full = out.toByteArray();
            return full;

        } catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            System.err.println("The File " + name + " is unsupported on this system.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Input-Output Exception on retrieval of file " + name);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

  static boolean soundless(byte[] s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i += 1) {
            if (s[i] != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'm not really sure what the issue could be at this point save for an operating system quirk that doesn't allow Java to access audio lines, but I do not know how to fix that - looking at System Preferences there isn't any obvious way to allow access. I think it might have to be done with terminal commands but also not sure of precisely what commands I'd have to execute there.

Comment: I did a search on "macos bigsur java audio" and found posts on audio issues. I didn't thoroughly go through the results, but the following link enumerates several installation steps involving to audio setup (3, 4, 5) for their application. https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050791811-macOS-11-Big-Sur-Apple-M1-Compatibility-Info Maybe this will be a good clue as to what system settings to search for and set. It does appear that BigSur is presenting challenges for many. I'm impressed and grateful for the work you are doing here to solve this.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209175 Are these system settings accessible via Java? IDK. ProTools is having major headaches! https://www.pro-tools-expert.com/production-expert-1/2020/10/21/macos-big-sur-compatibility-the-ultimate-pro-audio-guide-check-it-out-today

Comment: I'm currently working on setting up Universal Audio and checking those settings! I will update if there is anything new on that front. The system settings in the image are something I've checked but Java is not among the listed applications and the window does not let the user add new applications sadly! In the meantime I've made a post on Ask Different to see if there's any other Mac settings that are worth looking for

Comment: have you played these files out?? have opened them in some audio editor?? To rely on some other part of a faulty program to tell you if the program works is not always a safe technique - Works for me Fine in Win 10

Comment: @gpasch Yes, first thing I did was open the audio files in QuickTime Audio player and play them to check if there was any sound

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything wrong in the code you are showing. I haven't tried testing it on my system though. (Linux, Eclipse)

It seems to me your code closely matches [this tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api). The author *Nam Ha Minh* is exceptionally conscienscious about answering questions. You might try his exact code example and consult with him if his version also fails for you.

But first, what is the size of the resulting .wav file? Does the file size match the amount of data expected for the duration you are recording? If so, are you sure you have data incoming from your microphone? Nam has [another code example](https://www.codejava.net/coding/a-utility-for-recording-sound-in-java) where recorded sound is progressively read and placed into memory. Basically, instead of using the `AudioInputStream` as a parameter to the `AudioSystem.write` method, you execute multiple `read` method calls on the `AudioInputStream` and inspect the incoming data directly. That might be helpful for trouble-shooting whether the problem is occurring on the incoming vs outgoing part of the process.

I'm not knowledgeable enough about formats to know if the Mac does things differently. I'm surprised you are setting the format to *unsigned*. For my limited purposes, I stick with "CD quality stereo" and signed PCM at all junctures.

EDIT: based on feedback, it seems that the problem is that the incoming line is not returning data. From looking at other, similar tutorials, it seems that several people have had the same problem on their Mac systems.

First thing to verify: does your microphone work with other applications?

As far as next steps, I would try verifying the chosen line. The lines that are exposed to java can be enumerated/inspected. The tutorial [Accessing Audio System Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html) has some basic information on how to do this. It looks like `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` will return a list of available mixers that can be inspected. Maybe `AudioSystem.getTargetLineInfo()` would be more to the point.

I suppose it is possible that the default `Line` or `Port` being used when you obtain a `TargetDataLine` isn't the one that is running the microphone. If a particular line or port turns out to be the one you need, then it can be specified explicitly via an [overridden getTargetDataLine method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getTargetDataLine(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info)).

I'm reading that there might be a security policy that needs to be handled. I don't fully understand the code, but if that were the issue, an `Exception` presumably would have been thrown. Perhaps there are new security measures coming from the MacOs, to prevent an external program from opening a mic line surreptitiously?

If you do get this solved, be sure and post the answer and mark it solved. This seems to be a live question for many people.

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your response! I will check out the other code examples and see if I run into the same issue. As for the size of the resulting .wav file, when I use more standard settings than what I have in the code above (44100 sample rate, PCM_SIGNED, 2-channel etc) I get an audio file size that is 1.3 MB (2.1 on disk). Traditional wisdom says .WAVE is 10MB a minute, so 10 * 7.5/60 = 1.25 MB which seems to be in the ballpark

Comment: As an update: I ran the alternate code example separately on my computer to see if that would succeed, and it ended up with the same outcome (audio file of correct length is produced but with no sound). I've tried switching around the format as well (AIFF-C instead of WAVE) but to no avail

Comment: Interesting. I was just now looking at the questions on his tutorials, and it seems that the same problem has come up with other Mac users, and he has not answered questions on this. Also, the comments section seems to be malfunctioning. I'm going to edit my answer to add some additional suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the added suggestions! I updated my question with results - will look into OS protections on audio line

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you're encountering a similar issue to what I've experienced on my Mac with MacOS Big Sur and later versions. Like you, I was working with a basic audio-sampler program in Eclipse, and I also had to select the input device through the settings-sound panel.

The problem seems to be with the security manager. When I ran the program inside Eclipse, it gave me zero-value data from the device—no sound. However, upon exporting the program as a runnable JAR and running it from the command line, I got a prompt from the security manager asking for microphone access permissions. Once I allowed it, the program worked fine and read the audio data as expected.

It's clear that when running from Eclipse, the program isn't triggering the necessary permission prompt from the security manager. I'm also in search of a solution to get the security manager to prompt for microphone access when running the program within Eclipse. If you've made any progress or found a workaround, I'd be keen to hear it as well.

Comment: answer posts are not for asking questions or saying "me too".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35461395)